# nvenc encoder performed resolution 2560 * 1440 encoding yuv444 failed ？

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, nvidia, nvenc

NVIDIA Gefore GTX 1660Ti graphics card, I use video-sdk-samples for HEVC encoding, YUV format: NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT_YUV444, resolution “1920 * 1080” and “3840 * 2160” resolution encoding is successful, but resolution 2560*1440 encoding, prompting error info :NV_ENC_ERR_INVALID_PARAM, I do not know where the problem lies?

```
void NvEncoder::DoEncode(NV_ENC_INPUT_PTR inputBuffer, std::vector<bool> &vKeyFrame, std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> &vPacket, NV_ENC_PIC_PARAMS *pPicParams)
{
    NV_ENC_PIC_PARAMS picParams = {};
    if (pPicParams)
    {
        picParams = *pPicParams;
    }
    picParams.version = NV_ENC_PIC_PARAMS_VER;
    picParams.pictureStruct = NV_ENC_PIC_STRUCT_FRAME;
    picParams.inputBuffer = inputBuffer;
    picParams.bufferFmt = GetPixelFormat();
    picParams.inputWidth = GetEncodeWidth();
    picParams.inputHeight = GetEncodeHeight();
    picParams.outputBitstream = m_vBitstreamOutputBuffer[m_iToSend % m_nEncoderBuffer];
    picParams.completionEvent = m_vpCompletionEvent[m_iToSend % m_nEncoderBuffer];
    NVENCSTATUS nvStatus = m_nvenc.nvEncEncodePicture(m_hEncoder, &picParams);
    if (nvStatus == NV_ENC_SUCCESS || nvStatus == NV_ENC_ERR_NEED_MORE_INPUT)
    {
        m_iToSend++;
        GetEncodedPacket(m_vBitstreamOutputBuffer, vKeyFrame, vPacket, false);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("picParams.inputWidth = %d,picParams.inputHeight = %d \n", picParams.inputWidth, picParams.inputHeight);
        NVENC_THROW_ERROR("nvEncEncodePicture API failed", nvStatus);
    }
}

error:
nvEncEncodePicture Prompt Error：NV_ENC_ERR_INVALID_PARAM
```

`

Comment: You may check encoding 2560x1440 resolution using FFmpeg, example: `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf scale=2560:1440 -vcodec hevc_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv444p output.mp4`. I don't think the question is related to FFmpeg - the main subject is NVIDIA SDK. Please add `c++` tag. I don't think anyone can answer your question as it is (unless someone encouraged the exact same problem).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestion, I use ffmpeg to support 2560 * 1440 resolution, but I get an error when encoding with NVIDIA SDK, thanks.